# Hierarchical (three levels deep) Bayesian pymc3 model

Tags: pymc3

I am working on a Bayesian Hierarchical linear model in Pymc3.

The model consists of three input variables on a daily level: number of users, product category and product sku and the output variable is revenue. In total the data consists of roughly 73.000 records with 180 categories and 12.000 sku's. Moreover, some categories/sku's are highly present while other categories aren't. An example of the data is shown in the link:

[Preview of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx5I6.png)

As the data on sku level is very sparse an hierarchical model has been chosen with the intent that sku's with less data should shrink towards the category level mean and if a category is scarce the group level mean should shrink towards the overall mean.

In the final model the categories are label encoded and the continuous variables users and revenue are min-max scaled.

At this point the model is formalized as follows:

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    sigma_overall = pm.HalfNormal("sigma_overall", mu=50)
    sigma_category = pm.HalfNormal("sigma_category", mu=sigma_overall)
    sigma_sku = pm.HalfNormal("sigma_sku", sigma=sigma_category, shape=n_sku)

    beta = pm.HalfNormal("beta", sigma=sigma_sku, shape=n_sku)
    epsilon = pm.HalfCauchy("epsilon", 1)

    y = pm.Deterministic('y', beta[category_idx][sku_idx] * df['users'].values)
    y_likelihood = pm.Normal("y_likelihood", mu=y, sigma=epsilon, observed=df['revenue'].values)

    trace = pm.sample(2000)
```

The main hurdle is that the model is very slow. It takes hours, sometimes a day before the model completes. Metropolis- or NUTS sampling with find_MAP() did not make a difference. Furthermore, I doubt whether the model is formalized correctly as I am pretty new to Pymc3.

A review of the model and advice to speed it up is very welcome.